# Could not find support-compat.aar

Tags: android, android-studio

Getting this error and cannot seem to fix it?

```
Could not find support-compat.aar (com.android.support:support-compat:25.2.0).
Searched in the following locations:
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-compat/25.2.0/support-compat-25.2.0.aar

Please install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK Manager.
Open Android SDK Manager
```

Here is the gradle file:

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.crashlytics.tools.gradle:crashlytics-gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'crashlytics'

repositories {
    maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    //buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"  <-- have also tried 26.x.x here and fails

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.blah.tree"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 173
        versionName "1.0.163"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.crashlytics.android:crashlytics:1.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.1'
    compile 'com.github.gcacace:signature-pad:1.2.1'
}
```

Comment: You need to update all your dependencies

Comment: Have you check the support repository is installed?(The error message mentioned). 
I belived the IDE should also show the warning that the dependencies versions is not matched to the compileSdkVersion you use.